# Why am I not getting any images in my dot output?

Tags: macos, graphviz, dot

I've installed the Mac OS X binaries from the graphviz website and downloaded this test .dot file.

http://www.karakas-online.de/downloads/from-past-to-future.tgz

from this page:

http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2647

It produces an image, but none of the embedded images are visible.

Here's the output from the command "dot -v"

```
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.6.dylib
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.6.dylib
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_core.6.dylib
Using render: dot:core
Using device: dot:dot:core
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/local/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig gd map ps quartz svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  bmp canon cgimage cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps exr fig gd gd2 gif gv imap imap_np ismap jp2 jpe jpeg jpg pct pdf pict plain plain-ext png ps ps2 psd sgi svg svgz tga tif tiff tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) bmp eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg pdf png ps svg
```

This seems to imply that I can load images?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `style=invis` for each icon node. I don't know what was the author's idea in making it invisible. Worked for me on Win7.